# Comfy Mexican Sofa comfy_form_for remove form labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, comfortable-mexican-sofa

Does anyone know how to remove form labels? I have tried:

```
<%= comfy_form_for @comment, :as => :comment, options: {label: false}, :url => comfy_blog_comments_path(@cms_site.path, @blog.path, @post.slug) do |form| %>
```

also

```
<%= comfy_form_for @comment, :as => :comment, default: {label: false}, :url => comfy_blog_comments_path(@cms_site.path, @blog.path, @post.slug) do |form| %>
```

and also

```
<%= form.text_field :email, label: false, :class => 'form-control' %>
```

all to no avail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ComfortableMexicanSofa is using https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms

So I think you need to do this:

`<%= f.text_area :email, hide_label: true %>`

Answer (score 0):

Also for those wanting to completely remove the labels from the DOM, here is how to achieve it, according to [rails-bootstrap-forms](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms) docs you should do the following:

HTML:

```
 <%= form.text_area :content, :class => 'form-control', :rows => 5, placeholder: "Your comment", label_class: "removed-label" %>
```

CSS:

```
.removed-label {
  display: none;
}
```

Hope it helps someone down the line.